# Java, Dropbox Api V2 - Error while trying to make a longpoll request

Tags: java, android, dropbox-api

I use Dropbox Api V2 to synchronize application data in a folder. In order to track changes in my Dropbox directory I use long-polling. Here is my code from mDbxFile.java:

```
File f = new File("my_filepath");
DbxRequestConfig requestConfig = new DbxRequestConfig("my_prog/1.0", Locale.getDefault().toString());
DbxAuthInfo authInfo = DbxAuthInfo.Reader.readFromFile(f);
DbxClientV2 dbc = new DbxClientV2(requestConfig, authInfo.accessToken);
DbxFiles.ListFolderGetLatestCursorResult cursorResult = dbc.files.listFolderGetLatestCursor("");
DbxFiles.ListFolderLongpollResult longpollResult = dbc.files.listFolderLongpoll(cursorResult.cursor);
```

But when I execute it I get the following error:

```
com.dropbox.core.DbxException$BadRequest: Error in call to API function "files/list_folder/longpoll": Your request includes an Authorization header, but this function does not use it.
at com.dropbox.core.DbxRequestUtil.unexpectedStatus(DbxRequestUtil.java:262)
at com.dropbox.core.v2.DbxRawClientV2.rpcStyle(DbxRawClientV2.java:95)
at com.dropbox.core.v2.DbxFiles.listFolderLongpoll(DbxFiles.java:7678)
at com.dropbox.core.v2.DbxFiles.listFolderLongpoll(DbxFiles.java:7705)
at com.cramming_tools.draico.dbx.mDbxFile$1.run(mDbxFile.java:122)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The error is triggered by the last line.

Comment: Read the error.  It says that you're passing it an auth token, but this function doesn't expect one.  Try not sending up the authentication info.

Comment: The problem is that the authentication header is contained in the dbc object through which I'm making a request. Judged from the DB api v2 sources, the header is passed to the server by dropbox api itself. I'm just trying to find some workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue in the Dropbox Java SDK and will be resolved in a future update.

Comment: So, does this mean that there is no way to make a longpoll request in DB api v2 in its current state?

Comment: It's not currently possible with the SDK, but you can make the request directly to the HTTP endpoint: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-list_folder-longpoll

Comment: This should be fixed in version 2.0-beta-5.

Comment: Yes, updating to version 2.0-beta-5 has solved my problem. Thank you very much.